# Fixed width not being inherited by child elements

Tags: html, css, layout, width, fixed-width

So I’m currently working on a basic html web page that requires me to have a static layout and a fixed width of 1000px however when I do that I’m left with space on both the left and right of the page but when it’s on auto my elements such as my nav and other container elements take up the space etc take up the full width. What am I missing ??

Any help would be great! Thanks

Comment: The problem is that the browser is not *always* going to be exactly 1000px wide. Sometimes it will be more (leading to whitespace) and sometimes it will be less (leading to parts of the page getting cut off). Generally you want to go with a *responsive* design, so that it will display nicely on all devices. If you absolutely *must* go with a fixed width, you'll need to add your code for us to be able to help identify the specific problem.

Comment: Please provide a [repro] for debugging details. There is no way to tell why certain elements take up more than the 1000px width without debugging details.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't quite understand your question, but I think this is the solution

width:100%;

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/html-page-width-height

Comment: you miss the question. The question is why certain elements consume the entire width and not only 1000px

Answer (score -1):

As someone say in the commants, your page is not always x pixel size so It's hard to do but you can still do something like :

```css
body {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

But the things is that some people have a small screen so they will have a scrollbar or maybe you can use a lot of Breakpoint

Comment: you miss the question. The question is why certain elements consume the entire width and not only 1000px. defining the body width at 1000px will not center the element within.